# Supabase onAuthStateChanged - How do I properly wait for the request to finish prevent flickering with useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, supabase

Everything auth-wise is working fine. I even have a loading state setup so that the loader shows until the state is changed, but I still get this flickering on reload. This flickering only happens with Supabase. I was using the Firebase version before and it worked perfectly with my code.

Here is a video for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxGDn.jpg

Edit: Updated code to current version

```
export default function Navigation() {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthenticatedUserContext);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const session = supabase.auth.session();
    setUser(session?.user ?? null);

    const { data: listener } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((_: any, session: any) => {
      setUser(session?.user ?? null);
    });

    setIsLoading(false);
    return () => {
      listener?.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator color={Theme.colors.purple} size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={LinkingConfiguration}>{user ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}</NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, Supabase has released some updates since I first asked this question. Here is how I am now able to stop flickering when loading the application.

First, we need to set up our AuthContext for our application. Be sure to wrap your `App.tsx` with the `<AuthContextProvider>`.

AuthContext.tsx

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { Session, User } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

import { supabase } from '../config/supabase';

export const AuthContext = createContext<{ user: User | null; session: Session | null }>({
  user: null,
  session: null,
});

export const AuthContextProvider = (props: any) => {
  const [userSession, setUserSession] = useState<Session | null>(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {
      setUserSession(session);
      setUser(session?.user ?? null);
    });

    const { data: authListener } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(async (event, session) => {
      console.log(`Supabase auth event: ${event}`);
      setUserSession(session);
      setUser(session?.user ?? null);
    });

    return () => {
      authListener.subscription;
    };
  }, []);

  const value = {
    userSession,
    user,
  };
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />;
};

export const useUser = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error('useUser must be used within a AuthContextProvider.');
  }
  return context;
};
```

Now, if you're using React Navigation like me we need to check if we have a valid user to send them to the logged-in home screen. Here's how I do it.

Navigation.tsx

```
export default function Navigation() {
  const { user } = useUser();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={LinkingConfiguration}>
      {user ? <AppStackNavigator /> : <AuthStackNavigator />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: good stuff. you probably meant `authListener.subscription.unsubscribe()` in the return fn inside useEffect?

Answer (score 2):

To recap for others, `onAuthStateChange` will not execute on first page load so you are triggering it using the `getUserAuthStatus` async function. However `session()` function is not async and will immediately return a result of `null` if there is no user session, or return a session that has been stored in `localStorage`.

In this case the result of the `getUserAuthStatus` will always return null. Then `onAuthStateChange` will trigger with the `SIGNED_IN` event and a session which will then set the user.

Furthermore the `onAuthStateChange` function should be registered before you perform the session step so as to capture any events triggered. In the current form an event may be triggered directly after the `session()` call but before the handler is registered.

So to recap the rendering steps will be:

#### Step 1

```
isLoading: true
user: null
```

#### Step 2

```
isLoading: false
user: null
```

#### Step 3

```
isLoading false
user: {...}
```

So far as I can tell, using session directly without thinking it's async will do the trick.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for taking the time to answer. I tried using session directly but had no luck in stopping that flicker.

Comment: @MyPalVikram Do you want to try editing your code above with what you have and we'll go from there.

Comment: Note, that starting with Supabase's gotrue-js version 1.23 (once released), there will be a getSession() async method which should help with this issue: https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/releases/tag/v1.23.0-next.1. The reason why it would help is because you no longer need to manually check if user auth status is loading or not.

Comment: I don't think this response solves the problem. As noted by @Vik in the first comment

Comment: Noting that this answer is no longer valid for supabasejs v2

Answer (score 0):

React / Next Auth helpers provide decent help these days, so you do not need to write your own `useUser` or `useSession`: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers